# xamp port 8080 server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to run phpmyadmin as (http://localhost/phpmyadmin) not as (http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin) and not as (http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin).
I have changed the ports from `httpd.conf` but the same just run with 8080 as (http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xampp? What exactly did you change? And have you restarted the webserver after the changes?

Sounds a bit weird, usually webserver come with the standard port 80 as default.

Check "Listen" and "VirtualHost" entries. vhosts are either in httpd.conf, or in an extra file which is included from httpd.conf.

hth

Comment: Listen was 80, then changed it to 8080 and restarted the webserver and still need (http://localhost:8080/)

Comment: ehm... you changed it from 80 to 8080 - and wonder why it's listening on 8080?